# Emacs org-mode - How to run shell scripts with backgrounded processes without hanging Emacs

Tags: emacs, background-process, org-mode, freeze

Add this to an emacs .org file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results verbatim
  #!/bin/bash

  exec 2>&1  # <-- Because Emacs treats stderr output as an error and doesn't show it in the RESULT

  echo before 

  # This nohup should just run in the background and continue to exit
  # the script, but emacs hangs and waits on it anyhow:
  nohup sleep 10 &

  # Failed attempts at working around the hang are:
  #   setsid nohup sleep 10 &
  #   nohup sleep 10 </dev/null & 

  # Do see /tmp/ps.out being updated here so the hang is in Emacs:
  ps -ef --forest --cols=10000 >/tmp/ps.out

  echo after 

  exit 0
#+END_SRC
```

Move the point (cursor) into the BEGIN_SRC block and evaluate it using C-c C-c (which is bound to `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`).

Watch what happens.  Emacs sits there and hangs. What I want it to do is run that command (`sleep 10` in this trivial example) and continue on.

Somehow Emacs is trying to wait on all subprocesses that the script creates and hangs there. I have to hit C-g to get control back.

The use case for this is that I want to invoke some GUI application (xterm, etc.) and have it run in the background but give control immediately back to Emacs.

How can I do that? See my failed attempts above.

***EDIT***:  I isolated the issue to the bare minimum Emacs Lisp code. Evaluate the following inside your `*scratch*` (Lisp Interactive) buffer and see that it hangs for the 3 seconds:

```
(let ((shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
      (input-file "/tmp/tmpscript.sh")
      (error-file "/tmp/tmperror")
      (shell-command-switch "-c")
      (command "sh")
      exit-status)
  (with-temp-file input-file
    (insert "#!/bin/bash") (newline)
    (insert "nohup sleep 3 &") (newline)
    (insert "exit 0") (newline))
  (setq exit-status
        (apply 'call-process "/bin/bash"
                      input-file
                      (list t error-file)
                      nil
                      (list "-c" "sh"))))
```

Change the `sleep 3` to something like `sleep 3000` and it will hang for 3000 seconds until you kill it with C-g.

My emacs version reports:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) of 2014-09-14 on hungover
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async) from MELPA to enable asynchronous executions.

.emacs:

```
(require 'ob-async)
```

.org:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :async
sleep 10 && echo 'Done!'
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI: Since when I posted the question, I have since moved on to rolling my own solution that works similarly to ob-async, but instead writes the output of the block to a file, and then sends me a reminder after about 3s of inactivity in Emacs.  This allows me to have multiple background "jobs" running and when I'm paused, Emacs opens and moves point to the exact point of when the job was finished, and from there I can simply find-file the log file and view it. This is mandated because the logs produced by my background jobs are huge which will bloat the Org file if I inlined them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the closest I can think of using https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async

```
    * Run shell command asynchronously

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle some_cmd.sh :tangle-mode (identity #o755) :shebang #!/bin/bash
sleep 10
touch async-file
echo "done"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'async)

(org-babel-tangle)

(async-start
 (lambda ()
   (shell-command (expand-file-name "some_cmd.sh")))
 (lambda (result)
   (message-box "%s" result)))

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: #<process emacs>

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
ls async-file
#+END_SRC
```

or for your particular use:

```
(require 'async)

(async-start
 (lambda ()
   (shell-command "xterm"))
 (lambda (result)
   (message-box "%s" result)))
```

Comment: I'm not looking to run the entire script as a background process. I want to express, in Bash syntax, what subprocesses should be launched (my example is necessary a trimmed down version of the real script).  I've boiled the problem down to the bare minimum Emacs Lisp code, and posted that as an ***EDIT*** to my original post. This demonstrates that this is some interaction between `call-process` in Emacs and Bash.

Comment: Of course it does. Call-process is synchronous and waits for the process to finish.http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html. if you can't do it with asynchronous maybe look into start-process.http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes. You find some inspirations herehttp://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/11/20/Asynchronously-running-python-blocks-in-org-mode/.

Answer (score 1):

I am using emacs lisp `start-process`:

For example, to open libreoffice calc sheet

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes :results output :eval no-export :exports none 
(start-process "server" "buf-server" "libreoffice"  "calc.ods")
#+END_SRC
```

or to launch a java server (in the example tabula) in the background in xterm

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes :results output :eval no-export :exports none 
(start-process "server" "buf-server" "xterm"  "-T" "TABULA" "-hold" "-e"  "bash" "-c" "java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -jar ~/java/tabula.jar")
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

I use links.  I added `&` to the command for an sh link.  With `&` the process starts in the background:

```
[[shell:afplay '/path/to/20200523-20123124.m4a' &][sample link]]
```

I added `(setq org-confirm-shell-link-function nil)` b/c I have hundreds of small m4a files to transcribe ... this isn't safe to set but for now it's ok.

Running the link (with `C-x C-o`) opens a new org shell output window, but I just ignore it.

Cheers! z